# Managing and Playing Large videos

Tags: videos

I am implementing a blog to share courses, lectures, tutorials or talks.

The video sizes might be bit a bit big - so i was wondering what is a good quality plugin for wordpress that would allow to play videos smoothly , with different dpi settings and such.

I want to host the files on my hosting - and play them.

Is that a bad option, should i go to youtube ? 3rd party ? what are the + and - of each.
Are there any copyright issues, limits, "fair usages", forced ads ?

Any tips on the video thing is extremely welcomed.

I live in one of the top 5 countries with slowest internet, so optimizing this can be crucial.

Thanks for any advice you guys can share

Regards

Answer (score 4):

I just finished a Wordperss site that had a similar need for playing video. I would recommend going the Youtube route. Youtube will handle hosting, file conversions and with iframe embedding you can be sure the most devices possible will see your videos.

On the Wordpress side of the equation, there are many helpful plugins that work with Youtube. My personal favorite is [Tubepress](http://tubepress.org/).

Tubepress is great for making a playlist of just a few specific videos, or showing an entire archive of videos in pagination style. The customization available for displaying videos inline or in modal made it an easy choice for my custom theme.

If you're quite sure you're up to the challenge of hosting, properly encoding and serving video on your own, I'd recommend a two front assault. Use [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) as your easy-to-use Flash player for older browsers, and then embrace HTML5 for the newer browsers.

The best possible resource for all things HTML5 Video is [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html)

Comment: Hello PNMG - and thank you for your reply - did you take a look to http://www.kaltura.org/project/community_edition_video_platform , it looked quite professional, so i am considering doing some experimenting with it. do you recommend it / have any experience with it

Comment: I remember looking at Kaltura before choosing Flowplayer. I decided to take charge of controlling video encoding and hosting. I would definitely consider Kalture for a personal project, but most of my clients needs can be met with a mixture of Youtube hosting and Flowplayer for more branded video experiences.



As far as fair use and copy right concerns: if this is a large concern for you or your client host the files on Youtube. Youtube is responsible for monitoring their content. If there is a problem, Youtube will be held responsible (and just pull the video).

Answer (score 2):

Are you planning on converting the videos to .flv yourself? If not I would go with youtube/vimeo etc, it's easy to upload a video, get the embed code and job done.

If you have internal hosting (or better still a server and someone to manage it on the university network) then http://videopress.com/ might be worth a look.

Comment: with video press - i should publish to wordpress.com blog and then pull the video the self hosted using the id - this feels bit weird to me. as for youtube and such - i am wondering about ownership - ease of download and how safe it is to rely on 3rd party

Comment: Sorry - Videopress is actually installable on your own server if you have one but it takes some admin skills. It does all the conversion etc but it's not for a beginner. 

If you are doing it yourself and have no one to assist with server configuration try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stream-video-player/. This still requires some technical knowledge, but is a really very good.

If that one still seems too much, you'll have to upload to Vimeo/youtube etc and use any plugin to embed the videos into a post.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you put your videos on Youtube & Vimeo or similar video hosting server. These server has the hardware and bandwidth to stream your movies.

IF you choose to host these videos on your own server, you should create custom post types - I think. I'm pretty sure I saw some tutorials on thos, but I can't find it now.

But here are tuts for Custom Post types:

http://wpengineer.com/1969/impressions-of-custom-post-type
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-use-custom-post-types
http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress

**OR** you can use a plugin like JW Player: http://www.tubepress.net/wp-jw-player

Comment: are there any limits to youtube uploads ? like max upload/month quota or fair usage, max file size ? what about the content of the videos i upload there. i have a crappy internet connection - so the upload in FTP i can resume, same options in youtube ?

Comment: I've never uploaded a movie to Youtube, but I don't think you will ben using FTP. But here are some links you can look at: http://youtube-global.blogspot.com/2010/07/upload-limit-increases-to-15-minutes.html, http://gigaom.com/video/youtube-doubles-upload-size-limit/, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCAdwQm6FBc

Comment: Youtube has a web based interface for uploading movies. All you need is a web browser to upload to a Youtube account.

Answer (score 0):

jwplayer is good for this;
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/15995/jw-embedder-reference-guide#levels

upload 1 or more different versions of a video and it will detect the users' speed and select the appropriate quality.

also breaks down into html 5 for iphone/ipads too...

(try and avoid their wp plugin though as we've found it a bit dodgy and built it the player directly in our template)

Dc